# Check if an HTML element with the same id exists

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can this be done using javascript?

Comment: I think it would be wiser to check for multiple IDs before adding elements to the document - either at your server or at the client.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're trying to find out if more than one element share one id, with jQuery you could do `$('[id=blah]').length` - that will return a count of all elements where the id is equal to 'blah'. See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KUUJG/1/). If it's greater than 1 then you have a duplicate id.

**Edit:** I've tested this in Chrome, FF and IE6, and all of them show that there are two elements with the same id. I agree that it's really bad form to have more than one element share an id, but this code does work.

Comment: -1 for suggesting there could be several elements with id equal to 'blah'. :-)

Comment: @Marco - read the question: "Check if an HTML element with the same id exists" I think the OP is asking if you can check if multiple elements share the same id.

Comment: Just joking, because two elements with the same ID _must_not_happen_ but unfortunately I cannot remember any browser issuing a warning/debug error about that, that would be a good thing. About the downvote, I don't know, I stated it but didn't actually do that. Now i'm confused (and upvoting).

Comment: @Marco, don't worry, I know you didn't downvote, but someone did.

Comment: It's probably one of the anti-jQuery brigade, for suggesting that sometimes the easiest answer to a JavaScript question *might* be to use jQuery.

Comment: But if somebody didn't specify that they were already using jquery is it worth sucking in a big js library just to use one function when all the solution really requires is some simple javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe (if I understand the question)

```
if (document.getElementById('theId')) {
}
```

Comment: Was my initial thought, but I re-read the question and it might be the case that multiple elements may already exist with the same ID, in which case only one of them would be returned here.

Comment: Exactly, what if multiple elements with same ID already exist?

Comment: If you have multiple elements with the same ID, you have left the realm of valid HTML and can probably not get the DOM methods to work properly, especially across browsers.

Comment: The thing is i'm creating new HTML elements and I want to make sure that the id's i'm giving them haven't already been used. So i'm looking for a javascript that just lets me know that there is an id/or there are multiple id's with that name.

Comment: @Suss: then make that ID check *before* you're adding the element.

Comment: @Thilo, maybe, but it's possible with jQuery - see my answer.

Comment: If it's possible with jquery, then it's possible with javascript.

Comment: I have a related point. What if you have a section of html that you need a zillion times on the page, rather than have the server generate it, you just have javascript copy a source block (via innerhtml) only when the user needs a particular instance. This would result in the IDs being the same, and probably the need to change one of them and not the other. Alternatively you can create the dom elements on the fly, but if there's a LOT of them, innerhtml copy is easier and quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Also, in order to print all duplicates:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
var num = elems.length;
var ids = [ ];
for(i=0; i<num; i++ ) {
    var id = elems[i].getAttribute('id');
    if(id != null) {
        if(ids.indexOf(id) >=0 ) {
            console.debug(id); // found in table
        } else {
            ids.push(id); // new id found, add it to array
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!document.getElementById('search')) { return; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. 
iterate thru `document.getElementsByTagName('*')`, use `element.getAttribute('id')`